# Vue JS - How to do conditional display of text based on click event

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I just started learning Vue because I want to move from PHP to Javascript.

I have a question that I can't solved and I hope you can help me with it.

I have a list of tasks. I want to update the status if I completed the task. If I click, the set as complete link, the task would move from the incomplete tasks to the list of completed tasks.

[image]

You can see on the screenshot, the ***Buy milk*** is in the completed tasks. What I am trying to do is to add a ***"completed"*** text or a check icon beside ***"Buy milk"*** on the **All Task** list.

Here is my code:

```js
< script >
  var app = new Vue({
    el: '#root',
    data: {
      message: 'Hello world!',
      tasks: [{
          description: 'Go to the store',
          completed: false
        },
        {
          description: 'Buy milk',
          completed: false
        },
        {
          description: 'Feed the dog',
          completed: false
        },
        {
          description: 'Cook something',
          completed: false
        }
      ]
    },
    methods: {
      setToCompleted() {
        this.completed = true;
      },

    },
    computed: {
      incompleteTasks() {
        return this.tasks.filter(task => !task.completed);
      },
      completedTasks() {
        return this.tasks.filter(task => task.completed);
      }

    }
  }); <
/script>
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <h3>All tasks</h3>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="task in tasks" v-text="task.description == true ? 'Completed' : 'Not completed'"></li>
  </ul>

  <h3>Incomplete Tasks</h3>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="task in incompleteTasks">{{ task.description }}&nbsp|&nbsp<a href="#" @click="task.completed = true">Set as completed</a></li>
  </ul>

  <h3>Completed Tasks</h3>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="task in completedTasks" v-text="task.description"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

What I have tried Is I added a condition on a v-text directive. But it always show not completed. May you guide me why it is not changing? I would appreciate your help.

Thankyou.

***EDIT======***

This code solves my problem: thanks @tomrlh

```html
<div id="root">
  <h3>All tasks</h3>
  <li v-for="task in tasks">
    {{ task.description }} {{ task.completed ? 'completed' : '' }}
  </li>
  <h3>Incomplete Tasks</h3>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="task in incompleteTasks">{{ task.description }}&nbsp|&nbsp<a href="#" @click="task.completed = true">Set as completed</a></li>
  </ul>

  <h3>Completed Tasks</h3>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="task in completedTasks" v-text="task.description"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

what about to check if the task is completed in your *All Tasks* exhibition, then showing conditionally the 'completed' message:

```
<h3>All tasks</h3>
<li v-for="task in tasks">
    {{ task.description }} {{ task.completed ? ' | completed' }}
</li>
```